# How to set AES key is "private" in javascript?

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography

I have a demo code to encrypt and decrypt a string by using AES, like this:

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>

<script>

var password = $('#Password').val();

     var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(password, "0011");

     var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, "0011").toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8); 
 </script>
```

My question is: Is there a way to hide the key `0011` from javascript code?

I don't want any user can open my js file and view the key.

Thank you!

Comment: Obligatory reference: [Javascript Cryptography Considered Harmful](https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It is not possible.

You can't let the browser decrypt something without giving the browser the key.

The user controls the browser. Anything you give to the browser you also give to the user.

Comment: Thank you. You mean that: I don't want to encrypt the password before sending to server because attacker can open my js and decrypt it easily, don't you?

Comment: Yes. If you want to encrypt data when sending it between the browser and the server, use HTTP with SSL not JavaScript.

Comment: Not only all of the above, but if you are using that key for all of your security (not using a secure connection) then you aren't giving yourself or your website's visitor any protection from a man in the middle either.  You should use secure protocols and skip the AES in the JavaScript altogether.